# Browser refresh corrupts bundled javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, iis

I added ASP.NET javascript bundling and minfication to our website, and have discovered that now if I refresh the website, the bundled javascript file is downloaded as gzip but never uncompressed by the browser, so the site of course doesn't work since the javascript is still compressed.  If I refresh again, the site is fine.  Refresh again, corrupt.  Back and forth.  This is ONLY happening in Chrome and Safari, but not in IE.

Watching in Fiddler, IE gets the javascript the first time, and subsequent refreshes return 304 not modified which is correct.  Chrome / Safari refreshes continually return 200 for each refresh.

If I run my website locally hosting it in IIS Express, this problem does NOT occur.  It's only in our other QA, Staging and Production environments where the website is hosted by IIS 7.5.

I did a Fiddler compare of the good Chrome request and the bad Chrome request to see what's different.  They are identical except the bad request has the "If-Modified-Since" header.

The response from the server when the "If-Modified-Since" header is there has a Content-Type of "application/javascript", and this is what I think is causing the problem, the browser doesn't know it should uncompress the response body.

Here is the GOOD request and response (body omitted for brevity):

```
GET https://wwwq.website.com/Scripts/main.js?v=z3QOtK2bjf3mvSQyLf2KY82lAidw4JR0ePo01WHF93U1 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.website.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: https://www.website.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: < cookies omitted >

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 13:46:30 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sat, 04 Feb 2017 13:46:31 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 13:46:31 GMT
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Via: 1.1 wwwq.website.com (Access Gateway-ag-2772908347919084-467794)
Keep-Alive: timeout=300, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 62702
```

Here is the BAD request and response (body omitted for brevity):

```
GET https://www.website.com/Scripts/main.js?v=z3QOtK2bjf3mvSQyLf2KY82lAidw4JR0ePo01WHF93U1 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.website.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: https://www.website.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: < cookies omitted >
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 13:46:31 GMT


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 13:46:43 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Cache-Control: private
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 www.website.com (Access Gateway-ag-2772908347919084-467849)
Content-Length: 16042
Keep-Alive: timeout=300, max=94
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

If anyone can help me out I would be incredibly grateful I am running out of ideas.

Comment: What is `via` (Access Gateway..) ? Is that some front end lb/waf/etc? **If so**, could it be doing it's own thing (caching responses, etc.). Can you make requests that bypass it (directly to box) and see if same issue? Doubt this has to do with bundling - been using it for quite some time.